# How to align bottom of picture to ground when loading it?

Tags: image, 2d

I'm planing to do a simple animation of my drawings (scrolling and parallax effects with a camera).

Each time I'm loading a new *Image as Plane*, Blender align the center of the picture to the cursor, like this:

[image]

I was wondering if there's a way to automatically load the image ABOVE the Z axis, like this:

[image]

For now, i have to do this manually, which add quite many extra steps. Since I'm planning to load quite a lot of pictures, it would be a time saver.

I'm planning to have this type of result, just so you have a better idea of my humble project:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Current import *Images as Planes* addon doesn't have this feature ... so before some pythonist comes to help ... Blender is bundled with **Align Tools** addon. If you import all *Images as Planes* you can use addon to adjust them at once ...

Search for *Align Operator*
(or go to side panel (N) > *Item > Align Tools > Advanced*)

[image]

choose **Object** / X, Z / Min / Min it aligns all objects to left-bottom corner

[image]

then switch to **Pivot** / Active / Min to place Origin (Pivot point) also to left-bottom corner

[image]

Or use any other option ... to move all object to a *World Origin* (X0/Y0/Z0) press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. It will help me to save time by avoiding some repetitive manipulations.

Comment: You'r welcome :) Consider mark answer as accepted so others can see it as solved and system is not pocking it in repeatedly ... https://blender.stackexchange.com/tour ... You can change it anytime to another A, like if someone will extend or rewrite the addon for you. Thank you keep the site organised.

Answer (score 0):

Another way ... also not automated, but quite efficient is
under **Options** of 3D view header to *Affect only Origin*.

[image]

When enabled **Snapping** to *Vertex*

[image]

And <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> to Clear Location that now moves all images to zero location by bottom edges of images.